# Как задать в pythone если число меньше нужно то, вот такое действие

Tags: python

Например:

```py
Apple= 0
```

Если у вас яблока есть то

```py
Apple > 0:
print("Вы съели яблоко")
```

А вот если у вас нет яблок то

```py
Apple < 0
print("Вы не съели яблоко, потому что у вас его нет")
```

Comment: используйте оператор `if` https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/instrukciya-if-elif-else-proverka-istinnosti-trexmestnoe-vyrazhenie-ifelse.html

Comment: Да, но у меня идёт там выбор: if vubor == 2: и если я пишу if apple > 0: print("текст") то ничего нет

Comment: тогда покажите код. Если до того if точно доходит управление и при этом ничего нет, значит apple все таки не больше ноля. И проверку на отсутствие яблок лучше делать все таки `<=` а то ведь 0 под условие `<` не попадет

Answer (score 1):

```
Apple= 0
if(Apple == 0):
    print("Вы не съели яблоко, потому что у вас его нет")
elif(Apple > 0):
    print("Вы съели яблоко")
```